# Outputting the number of y's in one column that correspond to a condition in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling to output the number of "y"s that correspond to the last 5 "a"s in a data set of two columns, for example the first column contains cells occupied by either an "a" or "b". The second column contains cells that contain either a "y" or an "n". Is there a way of outputting the number of y's in column 2 corresponding for the last 5 a's of column 1? (The a's and b's are in no particular order).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of Excel that supports the new Dynamic Array feature, you can use this:

Column `A` has the 'a' / 'b' data and Column `B` has the 'y' / 'n' data

```
=SUM((FILTER(B:B,A:A="a")="y")*(SEQUENCE(COUNTIFS(A:A,"a"),1,COUNTIFS(A:A,"a"),-1)<=5))
```

---

How it works:

> ```
> FILTER(B:B,A:A="a")
> ```
>
> A Spill Range (1), Filter of 'y' / 'n' data where 'a' / 'b' data = 'a'

.

> ```
> (FILTER(B:B,A:A="a")="y")
> ```
>
> A Spill Range (2) of 'TRUE' / 'FALSE': 'TRUE' where Spill Range (1) = 'y'

.

> ```
> COUNTIFS(A:A,"a")
> ```
>
> Count of 'a' in Column `A` (= number of rows in Spill Range (1) )

.

> ```
> SEQUENCE(COUNTIFS(A:A,"a"),1,COUNTIFS(A:A,"a"),-1)
> ```
>
> A Spill Range (3) of numbers counting down from number of 'a' 's to 1

.

> ```
> (SEQUENCE(COUNTIFS(A:A,"a"),1,COUNTIFS(A:A,"a"),-1)<=5)
> ```
>
> A Spill Range (4) of 'TRUE' / 'FALSE': 'TRUE' where Spill Range (3) <= 5 (ie the last 5 'a' 's)

.

> ```
> SUM(( ... )*( ...))
> ```
>
> Sum of Spill Range (2) * Spill Range (4)
>   ie Sum( (Column A = 'a' and Column B = 'y') * (the 'a' is one of the last 5 'a' 's) )

Comment: I don't have the new version of Excel, but have verified that the formula works in Google Sheets if wrapped as an array formula (+1).

Comment: Thanks so much for this! that has really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Number of y's in Column B corresponding for the last 5 a's of Column A

Assume data housed in `A1:B20`

In `D4` enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+(INDEX(B1:B20,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A1:A20)/(A1:A20="a"),5)):B20="y"))
```

or,

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(B1:B20,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A1:A20)/(A1:A20="a"),5)):B20,"y")
```

[image]

Comment: I _think_ the OP means to only count "y"'s where Col A = "a" (so in your sample data the answer would be `1`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for older versions of Excel. Use Aggregate to get an array of the top 5 row numbers containing "a" then index with the n(if{1} construct to get an array of the corresponding values ("y" or "n") from column B. Test each of the values in this second array to see if they are equal to "y", use -- to convert them to ones and zeroes and Sumproduct to add them and make the formula work as an array formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},(AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A2:A20)/(A2:A20="a"),{1,2,3,4,5})))))="y"))
```

[image]